# I need To pass Data to Another flutter Page without navigating

Tags: flutter

I need To pass Data to Another flutter Page without navigating

Eg: in page 1 have a button clicking this button should store into selecteddocumentedId

so this documentid can i use in any another flutter page so i can get the data

```
    class _EeachWorkModelState extends State<EeachWorkModel> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return InkWell(
      onTap: () {},
```

In this on tap

```
widget.prolist['doc_id']
```

this should be passed without navigating to another screen

Comment: You don't do that type of logic. If you're using a library like Provider, you can update whatever value you need there and you'll consume later anywhere you want.

Comment: Can you include more details what are you trying to archive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the ID value to **persist** even after closing and reopening the app - **between app sessions**, you need to use *shared preference*, as described by the earlier contributor.

Otherwise, you might need to use state management to effectively store the state (i.e. the *selectedDocumentID*), such as **Riverpod** or **GetIt**.

I personally use Riverpod, and here's how it will work in Riverpod.

You will first need to add [flutter_riverpod](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_riverpod) package to you pubspec.yaml

Read the full initial setup by reading through this highly recommended [article](https://codewithandrea.com/articles/flutter-state-management-riverpod/). Particularly note the ProviderScope, using ConsumerWidget, Using Consumer and Using ConsumerStatefulWidget & ConsumerState sections.

Presuming the ID is a String, you can simply use state provider, initiate the ID value as empty String '' as below

```
final selectedDocumentIDStateProvider = StateProvider<String>((ref) {return '';});
```

Then set the document ID value by using

```
ref.read(selectedDocumentIDStateProvider.notifier).state = 'example_document_id'
```

And read the value anywhere within consumer widget using

```
final selectedDocumentID = ref.watch(selectedDocumentIDStateProvider);
```

If your selectedDocumentID is a complex object, or you need to implement a number of methods to the class, you should consider using notifier Provider instead of state provider.

Answer (score 1):

Use a persistent storage maybe like [shared_preferences](https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences)

Page one, on button event you set a value using a key and on any other page you read it using same key.

```
final SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
await prefs.setString('some_key', 'doc_id');
final String? action = prefs.getString('some_key');
```